# Sitecore Custom Analytics Report

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I know that Sitecore provides an option to offer **custom analytics report to the clients**. I successfully created a new report page following the steps given in the [official Sitecore documentation page](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/creating-a-custom-experience-analytics-report.html), choosing a metric and a segment in the parameters item [See Note (a)], ***but either it is throwing an error [see Note (b)] (OR) when I change to some other metrics and segments (thinking that it is a wrong combination of metrics/segments) - the custom report page shows as No data to display..!***

**My Questions:**
1. Does Sitecore has option/allows us to add any new metrics in the custom report that are not available in the standard analytics report?
2. If so, how I can find the list of those new metrics (with the right combination of metric/segment) that would show data without any errors? Atleast please name 3 of them for better understanding.

I understand that I need to have appropriate analytics data in my Sitecore instance, but I have those pattern matches data shown in the standard analytics report. In-short, for some combination of metrics/segments, it shows error and to some other combinations - it shows "No data to display"..!

Kindly assist. Thanks in advance

**NOTE**:
(a) **Category** : Audience Tab; 
**Metric** : Count;
**Segments** : All visits by pattern

(b) **ERROR MESSAGE** : 
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","exceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","stackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}